# Multi-color SVG polyline

Tags: javascript, svg, vector-graphics, leaflet, geojson

I'm using Leaflet to draw map data in SVG format on top of a map with javascript.  I have a set of thousands of coordinates, in which I'm drawing a Leaflet Path (extends L.Browser.svg).

I'd like to color code the line with a 3rd variable (since this is a map, say, altitude, blue being low and red being high, or something like that).  I'm new to SVG, but it seems like I can only set a stroke-color for the entire path.

E.g. What I have now -- line is just one color (Conceptual code stripped down for simplicity):

```
// create the SVG group and path element
this._container = this._createElement('g');
this._path = this._createElement('path');
// set the stoke color -- I wish I could make this dynamic per segment!
this._path.setAttribute('stroke', '#00000');

// Not real code, but simplified...generate lots of coordinates for the polyline
var myPath = "M" + p.x + "," + p.y + " L";
points.each(function(item, index){
    poly += item.x + "," + item.y + " ";                    
});

// update
this._path .setAttribute('d', poly);
```

Is there any better way to do this than create thousands of path elements and add them to the SVG group, each with it's own stroke color?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this but it is also a lot of work. If you have a complete image with the proper color coding [(something like this)](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0161642002010308-gr1.jpg), you can use an SVG filter to composite that image with your path: instant path coloring. You can probably also use an SVG mask to achieve the same effect. If you don't have that image, then you can construct one in SVG, but it's probably going to be a similar amount of work.

Comment: I don't have the image.  I have an array of X Point, Y point, and color.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: I think you're just better off setting stroke color per path segment.

Comment: Is there a better way to do that, other than creating an array of path elements (createElement('path'))?  Can I access the subsgements of a group or path?  I couldn't find anything in searching.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I believe only the path object as a whole can be styled.